# Use a Table in a Database as a template for a Wiki

Tags: php, html, database

I would like to be able to create the small information box/tables on Wiki's that normally appears on the right. I have tables in a database which have 16 basic columns for it, but I'm not too sure how to link them to a table then add data to it on a case by case basis. Can anyone help? 
Examples from a couple of sites:

[Wikipedia Version](https://snag.gy/WhVj29.jpg)

[Armored Warfare Wiki Version](https://snag.gy/4tK2rx.jpg)

Code is here:   https://www.writeurl.com/text/9i8zl45juivk920xwirq/bj7oqjvnu7bo57ux10r2

Comment: please edit the database table you want to show. and be more specific of what you want to try to show an example if you are unable to describe it.

Comment: I did edit the question @SayedMohdAli

Comment: You should also show some effort that you've made - we aren't here to really build a solution for you.

Comment: first make database connection > then fetch data from table using query > then design html part with table and box ...

 you also need to show how far you have done with it the coding part. your database table, html/php file

Comment: @SayedMohdAli I added a link to my code, as this site kept giving up with indentation errors when I tried to put it directly into the edit.

Comment: Sorry, I rarely use this site @Adam so apologies for any issues I incurred.

Comment: please never share live credentials in code.

Comment: In your code you have already fetched the data and created the table you want? what help do you need?

Comment: @SayedMohdAli I have a general table, but I wanted to be able to input my own data into it, depending on the page I am on. For example, if I am on a page that is about a particular vehicle, I would like to be able to edit what comes out on the table contents, so that I don't have to create a new table for every vehicle I do.
Sorry, I am quite inexperienced with things like PHP, so this is fairly confusing at points for me.

Comment: okay for each page you need to pass query string on the page url 

like when you are on car page 
car.html?page=car

now $page = $_GET["page"];
and use this $page in your query to get the desire data

Comment: SELECT *  FROM td_germany where pageid = $page

Comment: like that you can get dynamic data

Comment: Alright thank you, almost wish was an Answer so I could tick it off @SayedMohdAli

Comment: @MindlessFox I have posted it as an answer now you can tick it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay for each page you need to pass query string on the page URL like when you are on car page `car.html?page=car` now `$page = $_GET["page"];` and use this `$page` in your query to get requested data from database.

Query example is below:

```
  SELECT * FROM td_germany where pageid = $page
```